# Uses for Scanner() other than console

Tags: java, methods

Reading through a lot of beginner tutorials and books I noted:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Can be used to print something into the console and save whatever input the user types in. Does this have any other implementations other than when the user has access to the console of the IDE?

I know `System.in` is system input but what else can be placed in the `Scanner` method?

Answer (score 5):

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). You can construct a `Scanner` to read from a `File`, an `InputStream`, a `Readable`, a `Path` or a `ReadableByteChannel`.

Comment: Not to mention reading from a `String`. Sometimes using a `Scanner` is the easiest way to parse a string, when everyone's first impulse, it seems, is to haul out regular expressions.